# Combining yeoman angular and jhipster generators

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I would like to combine the two generators [jhipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) and [angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular).
The jhipster entity generator generates entities for both spring/JPA and angular route/view/controller.
A REST point is not always linked to a view, hence I would want to generate the java and angular parts separately. Are there common practices for these issues?

Comment: I think this is a valid question still.

I am looking into jHipster, and trying to figure out if i can use angular-fullstack (ie) to generate the routes etc. on top of jhipster

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested out the JHipster framework itself? I hate to ask such a basic question, but if you look at the structure of what is being delivered by hipster, you'll notice that the Spring API controllers/endpoints are all going to be under your `main/java/com/[projectname]/web/rest` folder, and your Angular calls to those endpoints will all be mapped under the `/webapp/scripts/` folder as part of your Angular `services` file. If you simply want to remove the Angular views and customize, it should be as easy as deleting those files from your project.

However, if you are looking for another form of REST scaffolding tool, my suggestion is to look up http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo if you want to go build based on your entities or DDL2HBM if you want to build based on an existing DB.